# How many back propagations to run on a single entry of new data in online machine learning using neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I want my neural network to be trained on every new data that it classifies incorrectly. Assuming that I somehow label the data correctly every time the network makes a mistake, how many back props do i need to run on this single instance of new data in order to train my network for that particular case? Is there a better way to train a neural network on real time scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the optimization algorithm you use. The backpropagation by itself calculates only the gradient, which is used by the next iteration of the algorithm.

In the simplest case you can use a self-developed gradient descent and check the behavior of your cost function. If the cost function decreases less than some threshold `epsilon`, you might break the optimization loop for the current instance. You can also limit the maximum number of iterations.

It is worth  using some advanced optimizers such `fminunc` in Matlab, which will stop by themselves when reached an optimum.

You may find [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33136/how-to-define-the-termination-condition-for-gradient-descent) post about different termination conditions of gradient descent very useful.

I think, learning only using one single instance is not really efficient. The cost function can behave jerky. You may consider the batch learning method, where you learn using small batches of new instances. It should provide a better learning rate.

In order to illustrate how network's accuracy depends on the iteration number and on the batch size, I experimented a bit with a neural network used to recognize hand written digits. I had 4000 examples in the training set  and 1000 examples in the validation set. Then I started the learning algorithm with different parameters and measured the resulted accuracy. You can see the result here:

[image: neural network accuracy as a function of iteration numbers and batch size]

Of course this plot describes only my particular case, but you can get some intuition on what to expect and on how to validate network parameters.